# Python one liner for multiple averages of unsorted list

Tags: python

I have data in the form of

```
Ns0 = [ 2 3 1 2 2 3 4 5 3 1 2 ]
As0 = [ 9 2 4 5 4 3 1 2 0 8 2 ]
```

and I would like to create `Ns = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]` as well as `As_avg` which is the average of all items in `As0` associated `Ns0`.

I know I can make `Ns` with `Ns = list(set(Ns0))` and I was hoping to make `As_avg` in the following way:

```
for N in Ns:
    As_avg.append( np.mean( np.array( [a for a in As0 if ??? ] ) ) )
```

but I'm stuck on the `???` portion. How do I select `a` in `As0` which corresponds to `N` in `Ns0`?

I know I can just do this in the following manner:

```
for N in Ns:
    tlist = []
    for (tN, tA) in zip(Ns0, As0):
        if( tN == N ):
            tlist.append(tA)
    As_avg.append( np.mean( np.array( tlist ) ) )
```

but I was hoping for a more pythonic way of doing this

Comment: I don't believe it makes it more pythonic to have it as a single liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for N in Ns:
    As_avg.append( np.mean( np.array( [tA for tN, tA in zip(Ns0, As0) if tN == N]  ) ) )
```

But don't try to be 'pythonic' if it's a trade-off for readability. I prefer the 2 loop version personally.

Comment: bonus points for clarification on being 'pythonic', readability is always appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary for preserving your expected items which the keys are unique items from `Ns0` and the values are lists of corresponding items in `As0`, then apply the `np.mean` on values using `map` function:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> 
>>> for i,j in zip(Ns0, As0):
...     d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
... 
>>> map(np.mean, d.values())
[6.0, 5.0, 1.6666666666666667, 1.0, 2.0]
```

**Note** that the advantage of this approach is that you don't have to create a list of unique items from `Ns0` and then you can simple use one loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that readability is one of the key Python values https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

List and dict comprehensions can be great for this, but if they get too complicated they make it too hard to read, and you should split them into multiple lines.

This is how I would solve the problem, I think:

```
common_vals = [A_val for A_val, N_val in zip(As0, Ns0) if A_val == N_val]
As_avg = np.mean(np.asarray(common_vals))
```

I have assumed that you only want `common_vals` to contain values that appear in both lists, AND appear in the same position.  If you only want values that appear in both lists:

```
common_vals = [val for val in As0 if val is in Ns0]
```

I would also point out that capital letters in variable names is usually bad in Python, as it is against the PEP8 style guide https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/  If you're dealing with matrices I can understand capitals sometimes making a lot more sense, though :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I noticed that your As_avg variable is a list -- is this deliberate?